# Is it possible to link to other static pages in a Timber template?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

Currently, to link to a "FAQ" page, I have the following:

```
Check out our <a href="{{ site.link }}/faq">FAQ</a> page.
```

However, I'd like to be able to link to other internal pages in my WordPress theme without manually writing in the URL parameters after it. Something like:

```
Check out our <a href="{{ site.link('faq') }}">FAQ</a> page.
```

Is this not possible in Timber? I've checked through the docs but don't see any references to it, but I feel like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress has two functions to resolve it: [get_page_by_path()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) and [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

```
get_page_by_path('page-slug');
get_permalink(page_id);
```

Using Timber you could write something like this [calling a Timber function](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/):

```
{{ function('get_permalink', function('get_page_by_path', 'page-slug')) }}
```

But sure, you should define a wp function to not be insane. You can add functions to WordPress using the functions.php file, even you should have defined a class to [extends Timber](https://github.com/timber/starter-theme) (if not, copy and paste it)

```
class StarterSite extends Timber\Site {
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'timber/twig', array( $this, 'add_to_twig' ) );
        add_filter( 'timber/context', array( $this, 'add_to_context' ) );
        $this->add_routes();
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function add_to_context( $context ) {
        $context['menu']  = new Timber\Menu();
        $context['site']  = $this;      
        return $context;
    }

    public function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
        $twig->addFunction( new Timber\Twig_Function( 'get_permalink_by_slug', function($slug) {
            return get_permalink( get_page_by_path($slug) );
        } ) );
        return $twig;
    }

}
new StarterSite();
```

As you can see [I defined a Twig function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html) named get_page_by_slug that receives a string with the page slug. Now, you can write it on your templates:

```
{{ get_permalink_by_slug('page-slug') }}
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the pages into your context using the filter timber_context

```
add_filter('timber_context', 'add_to_context');

function add_to_context($context){
    /* this is where you can add your own data to Timber's context object */
    $extraLinks = [];
    $extraLinks['faq'] = get_permalink($faq_ID);
    $context['site']['extraLinks'] = $extraLinks;
    return $context;
}
```

So you can call in your twig file

```
Check out our <a href="{{ site.extraLinks.faq }}">FAQ</a> page.
```

[source](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/36#issuecomment-22140454)

Comment: Not entirely the way I assumed, but definitely a good resolution. I may just turn this into an `array()` for common top-level pages...